# Best websites to do automation testing

Tags: automated-testing

I know this is more of a general question,  I would like to get some details on the websites that I could use to do automation testing for learning purpose. I'm looking to a website which have complexity.

Comment: Stack Exchange :D

Answer (score 1):

Let's get practical here.

You are learning automation so that you can get a job or project.
Sites like Mercury Tours are good to practice but in real world actual websites/apps are much complex then this one.

If you want to learn and practice automation, go for the real website/app. 
For example, automate your network service provider's website or app. As you are practicing, you can use your credentials, login into the web/app and then try to fetch information or change your setting and reset them back.
That's how I started and got really good hands-on.

Comment: Based on your answer, are you the one who downvoted mine?

Comment: @billhileman no buddy. It was devoted already.

Comment: Fair enough.  Your point is well-taken, but the OP did ask for some sites, and it's also fair to assume he/she's a beginner, so suggesting a web site for a relative beginner might be a good idea rather than just suggesting ones more complex than Mercury Tours.  There are lots out there, but there a tons more that would be overwhelming to a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate your application which you are working in the company. It will be helpful for you to familiar the project or products and even you have good understanding about that project how it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have started with the travel websites they usually cover all the real time scenarios.

I started my journey with these websites.

Answer (score 0):

To learn is also very good Facebook. I did my first experiments with Python and Selenium. Login process, logout on Facebook.

One can expand his test according to the knowledge more and more. Upload, integrate the Facebook Api, there are no limits.

There are also very good beginner tutorials that also advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have basic knowledge of all the concepts of automation testing then try to automate any e-commerce website. Number of such websites available. Do you practice hard on one website and try to automate full functionality of it. Best of luck :)

Answer (score -1):

This is the site I used:

[Mercury Tours](http://newtours.demoaut.com/)

It's quite old, but it's actually a pretty good test site.

Comment: Bill Hileman
Thanks for the share!